# Selecting nearest hidden input

Tags: jquery

I have the following divs:

```
     <div class="vote">
     <input type="hidden" name="reply-id" value="83743">
     <a class="vote-up-0" title="Vote Up This Comment">up</a>
     <a class="vote-down-0" title="Vote Down This Comment">down</a>
     </div>


     <div class="vote">
     <input type="hidden" name="reply-id" class="reply-id" value="83745">
     <a class="vote-up-0" title="Vote Up This Comment">up</a>
     <a class="vote-down-0" title="Vote Down This Comment">down</a>
     </div>
```

(Yes, it's a blatent(ish) copy of SO code, I'm trying to see how they do it).
So when a user clicks either vote up or vote down, it should find the hidden id.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
       $('a.vote-up-0').click(function() {

           var id = $(this).closest('.reply-id').val();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`closest` works by going up the DOM tree to find the first element that matches a selector.  It **only** matches ancestor elements.  At no point does it look at sibling elements.

You want to use [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings):

```
$(this).siblings('.reply-id').val();
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to generalise it slightly, to work with any `input`-element names, without necessarily knowing the names of the parent elements, you could use:

```
var idOfHiddenInput = $(this).parent().find('input:hidden:first').attr('id');
```

References:

- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [`:hidden` selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector)

Comment: What if i know the input's name, Do i do like .find('.reply-id') ?

Answer (score 3):

Why not attach the ID as a custom attribute to the clickable object itself. Then you can just access it with `.attr`. You could for example put a `val` tag like this:

```
<a class="vote-up-0" title="Vote Up This Comment" val="2345">up</a>
```

then access it with

```
$(this).attr("val")
```

This might eliminate the need for the hidden field

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.vote-up-0').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).parent().find('.reply-id').val();
    });
});
```

Comment: There is no `parent` property of a jQuery selection. You mean `parent()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are wrapping the hidden element inside a div you can use the below method too.

```
$(this).closest('div').find('input[name="reply-id"]').val()
```

This will proceed to the closest DOM element and will find the hidden input element with the name "reply-id".